# Import data from file.json with mongoose

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to import data from many json files with mongoose, but I can't seem to  find how.
Now I'm just importing the files using mongoDB commands:

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName --file fileName.json --jsonArray
```

Is there a way to do it with mongoose? is it the right way to do it with mongoose (I'm using expressJs)? if not what's the right way to populate my database with data from json files?

This is what I've done so far in server.js

```js
/ Set up
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); // create our app w/ express
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); // mongoose for mongodb
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID; // objectID
var morgan = require('morgan'); // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)
var cors = require('cors');

// Configuration
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/data');

app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 'extended': 'true' })); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

// Models
var Review = mongoose.model('Review', {
    title: String,
    description: String,
    rating: Number
});
var Site = mongoose.model('Site', {
    title: String,
    description: String,
    rating: Number
});

// Routes

// Get reviews
app.get('/api/reviews', function(req, res) {

    console.log("fetching reviews");

    // use mongoose to get all reviews in the database
    Review.find(function(err, reviews) {

        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err)
            res.send(err)

        res.json(reviews); // return all reviews in JSON format
    });
});
```

Comment: Just create a loop in your shell script. Writing something to parse and insert from JSON sources yourself is kind of redundant when a tool already exists that performs the function. It's not an overly difficult task, but unless it's something you have actually done quite a few times before it can be difficult "to do right". You also are not likely able to beat the performance. `mongoimport` and the other tools are written at pretty low level using Go, and are no slouches at what they do.

Comment: I see, so there is no other way. Thank you. Can you write this as an answer so I can close this post ?

Comment: It's not that there is "no other way". it's simply not "worth the time" to go and write a program that already exists, and will actually do a better job than anything you are likely to write. So it's just a logical choice really.

Comment: Alright I'm gonna leave this open in case a better solution appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same issue, Using mongoimport bypasses the schema and makes the schema type checking and validation useless. So, what I did works fine for a single json object. I am planning in extending it to work on the whole json file. So, I have a POST request which adds data to the mongoDB  going through schema. I made a curl script to make that same post request and does go through the schema. Here is my curl script.

```
curl \
--header "Content-type: application/json" \
--request POST \
--data @data.json \
http://localhost:3000/supplierList
```

I have a json object in the data.json file. Here is how it looks like.

```
{
    "supplierName": "KINGCOBRA",
    "price": "12345678911234567.00000000000000001",
    "basicDate": "2045/03/23",
    "currency": "USD",
    "partName": "ASDF",
    "description": "First Object: TEST 1: POST Inserting an array of object through the script",
    "volume": 2334
}
```

The only problem with this approach is that it does not support insertation of json array.But it will work for single object regardless of it's size. Let me know if anyone found a workaround for that.

Comment: A good start, we just need to find out a way for json array now